# date-fns : tree-shaking doesn't seem to work

Tags: webpack, date-fns, tree-shaking

I use only a few of the functions and made sure I import them as recommended for tree-shaking in their documentation :

```
import { parseISO, formatDistanceToNow } from 'date-fns'
import { fr } from 'date-fns/locale';
```

The code itself works fine, but when I look at the resulting JS bundle, the entire libray (all functions) along with all of the locales are bundled, resulting in ~1,37mb > parsed 600kb > Gzipped 111kb. I use NuxtJS (bundling with webpack) and the latest date-fns (2.27.0).

Here is the bundle generated :

[image: Here is the bundle generated]

Based on the answer to this similar question :
[date-fns 2 - can't get tree-shaking to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57857096/date-fns-2-cant-get-tree-shaking-to-work)
I've double-checked the final webpack config generated by nuxt, and it contains as expected `mode: production`. I am not using TypeScript on this project.

Also went through several related github issues like this one :
https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/2589

None of the answers worked in my situation... what can I do to make the tree-shaking happen properly ? Let me know if you think my question is missing some information :)

Comment: Check https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/2207 . It might be some version issue. You can also try going with direct imports or rewrite the imports with webpack or a similar tool.

Comment: Thanks, but it still happens with the latest version (2.28.0 right now). I've opened a new issue about this on date-fns repo here https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/3004 but so far no reply or progress.

Comment: I'll post a solution to keep people updated if/when there is a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for tree-shaking the date-fns locales that worked for me, using a Webpack alias (found the solution [in this Github issue](https://github.com/react-component/picker/issues/232#issuecomment-906209951)).

1. Create a file called for example `date-fns-locales.js` next to your webpack config where you will re-export the functions you use in your project like this :

```
export { default as enGB } from 'date-fns/locale/en-GB';
export { default as enUS } from 'date-fns/locale/en-US';

export { default as fr } from 'date-fns/locale/fr';
// ...etc
...
```

2. Then, add an alias your Webpack config :

```
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'date-fns/locale$': require.resolve('./date-fns-locales.js')
        }
    },
```

In my particular case, using Nuxt.js for Webpack bundling I added this in nuxt.config.js instead :

```
extend (config, ctx) {
   config.resolve.alias['date-fns/locale$'] = require.resolve('./date-fns-locales.js');
   ...
}
```

Every time you import something from `date-fns/locale` it will look up the import using the alias, avoiding the full import of all locales.

This solved the problem for me and greatly reduced the bundle size.

I still haven't worked out how to achieve the same result for the actual date-fns functions.